# Architectural decision for asynchronous API requests for queue of dependent messages

Tags: php, soap, architecture, mq

I need to implement some script for exporting data from one service to another. Origin service has written using PHP language. Destination service has an SOAP API with MQ under the hood so every request to that API is converted into message which goes into queue and waiting to be processed. API server responses to this request only with message ID so I need to perform one or multiple extra request with that message ID as a param to get status and result of processing my initial request.

The main problem is that I have a lot of data to be processed where next request depends on the result of the previous request. I'm going to use some kind of MQ service on the client side to make client "to wait" for the result of the successful processing of the previous request. Currently there are 2 such services in our project's stack: Kafka and Gearman. It would be great to solve topic problem using these without requirement to set up some additional services.

Exporting data mainly will consist of hierarchical structures with folders and complex composite elements. For example, imagine some structure:

```php
[
  'title' => 'Cars',
  'folders' => [
    [
      'title' => 'Chevrolet',
      'folders' => [],
      'files' => [
        ['file' => '/path/to/images/dir/camaro.jpg'],
        ['file' => '/path/to/images/dir/tahoe.jpg']
      ]
    ],
  ]
]
```

I have to reproduce exact structure on the destination service through API. So according to API's features I have to perform multiple requests:

```php
// Ask API to create folder
>>> ['action' => 'create-folder', 'name' => 'Cars', 'parent' => 'null']
// Get ID of the message in queue
<<< ['status' => 'received', 'message-id' => 123]
// Request message status
>>> ['action' => 'get-message-result', 'message-id' => 123]
// Get ID of the created folder
<<< ['status' => 'created', 'folder-id' => 1]

// Perform next request using ID of created folder as parent ID
>>> ['action' => 'create-folder', 'name' => 'Chevrolet', 'parent' => 1]
<<< ['status' => 'received', 'message-id' => 124]
>>> ['action' => 'get-message-result', 'message-id' => 124]
<<< ['status' => 'pending']
// ... Maybe rerun request multiple times because of server delays
>>> ['action' => 'get-message-result', 'message-id' => 124]
<<< ['status' => 'created', 'folder-id' => 2]

// Upload physical file
>>> ['action' => 'upload-file', 'path' => '/path/to/images/dir/camaro.jpg']
<<< ['status' => 'received', 'message-id' => 125],
>>> ['action' => 'get-message-result', 'message-id' => 125]
// Get path to the uploaded file, generated by server
<<< ['status' => 'created', 'file-name' => '/tmp/_190402934.jpg'],

// Create DB record linked to that physical file
>>> ['action' => 'create-file', 'path' => '/tmp/_190402934.jpg'],
<<< ['status' => 'received', 'message-id' => 126],
>>> ['action' => 'get-message-result', 'message-id' => 126]
<<< ['status' => 'created', 'file-id' => 100],
// ... and so on
```

The main thing that I want to show is that one request is dependent on another. Result of request does not contain data about success, only ID of message in queue so to get result data it is required to perform unknown number of extra requests after main. And only after receiving of required data (e.g. ID of created folder) client's queue can go to the next step.

Could you help me with your suggestions with effective way to implement this? Whether it possible to implement using Gearman or/and Kafka?

Whether it is possible to set some constraint on client's MQ which will restrict service to start next API request only after receiving required result of previous request (regardless of delay and number of 'get-message-result' extra requests between main request and actual result of processing that request)?

Maybe you could suggest some examples, articles or books where similar problems were solved?

Comment: Just so you know: I read it all, it is quite interesting, but it is hard to make any suggestions. Perhaps this question is a bit to broad for Stack Overflow? All I know is that this can, very quickly, get very complicated. What to do when a request cannot be fulfilled?

Comment: Yup, that is a problem also. There are a lot more questions, but I don't take them into consideration right now. I'd like to get some suggestions for direction to investigate about the possible solutions. I also admit that my knowledge about MQs possibilities may be not enough to solve such problems. That's why my question is here - just to get some advice where to dig to. I'll appreciate any useful information.